# преобразование кода C++ в HTML

Tags: html, c++, css, текст, sublime-text

Как отобразить следующий код C++ в HTML? Мне нужно для примера вставить его на свой сайт. Оборачивание в `<code>`не помогает. Проблема здесь в кавычках, в коде C++. Как исправить?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
 int n,m,i=3,j=3;
  cout<<"At the beginning:\n";
  cout<<"i = "<<i<<"\n";
  cout<<"j = "<<j<<"\n";
  cout<<"After command n=i++ :\n";
  n=i++;// Теперь n=3, а i=4
  cout<<"n = "<<n<<"\n";
  cout<<"i = "<<i<<"\n";
  cout<<" After command m=++j :\n";
  m=++j;// Значение переменных m=4 и j=4
  cout<<"m = "<<m<<"\n";
  cout<<"j = "<<j<<"\n";
  cout<<" After command n=(--i)*(i--) :\n";
  n=(--i)*(i--);// Теперь n=9, а i=2
  cout<<"n = "<<n<<"\n";
  cout<<"i = "<<i<<"\n";
  cout<<" After command m=(--j)*(--j) :\n";
  m=(--j)*(--j);// Теперь m=4, а j=2
  cout<<"m = "<<m<<"\n";
  cout<<"j = "<<j<<"\n";
  cout<<" After command n=(--i)*(i++) :\n";
  n=(--i)*(i++);// Теперь n=1, а i=2
  cout<<"n = "<<n<<"\n";
  cout<<"i = "<<i<<"\n";
  cout<<" After command m=(j--)*(++j) :\n";
  m=(j--)*(++j);// Теперь m=9, а j=2
  cout<<"m = "<<m<<"\n";
  cout<<"j = "<<j<<"\n";
  cout<<" After command n=(--i)*(++i) :\n";
  n=(--i)*(++i);// Теперь n=4, а i=2
  cout<<"n = "<<n<<"\n";
  cout<<"i = "<<i<<"\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не понял, в чем проблема? Вам надо `&quot;`?

Comment: Нет, мне не нужны пробелы. Мне нужно этот код для примера вставить в HTML страницу

Comment: А как насчет тега [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)?

Comment: тоже пробовал, не помогает. и в <pre> + <code> тоже оборачивал

Comment: А при чем пробелы к `&quot;`?

Answer (score 1):

Ну вам придется либо вручную переписывать все это дело в html последовательность либо использовать некоторые сервисы как этот: https://url-decode.com/tool/html-encode

Выхлоп:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <code><pre>#include&lt;iostream&gt;
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n,m,i=3,j=3;
    cout&lt;&lt;"At the beginning:\n";
    cout&lt;&lt;"i = "&lt;&lt;i&lt;&lt;"\n";
    cout&lt;&lt;"j = "&lt;&lt;j&lt;&lt;"\n";
    cout&lt;&lt;"After command n=i++ :\n";
    n=i++;// Теперь n=3, а i=4
    cout&lt;&lt;"n = "&lt;&lt;n&lt;&lt;"\n";
    cout&lt;&lt;"i = "&lt;&lt;i&lt;&lt;"\n";
    cout&lt;&lt;" After command m=++j :\n";
    m=++j;// Значение переменных m=4 и j=4
    cout&lt;&lt;"m = "&lt;&lt;m&lt;&lt;"\n";
    cout&lt;&lt;"j = "&lt;&lt;j&lt;&lt;"\n";
    cout&lt;&lt;" After command n=(--i)*(i--) :\n";
    n=(--i)*(i--);// Теперь n=9, а i=2
    cout&lt;&lt;"n = "&lt;&lt;n&lt;&lt;"\n";
    cout&lt;&lt;"i = "&lt;&lt;i&lt;&lt;"\n";
    cout&lt;&lt;" After command m=(--j)*(--j) :\n";
    m=(--j)*(--j);// Теперь m=4, а j=2
    cout&lt;&lt;"m = "&lt;&lt;m&lt;&lt;"\n";
    cout&lt;&lt;"j = "&lt;&lt;j&lt;&lt;"\n";
    cout&lt;&lt;" After command n=(--i)*(i++) :\n";
    n=(--i)*(i++);// Теперь n=1, а i=2
    cout&lt;&lt;"n = "&lt;&lt;n&lt;&lt;"\n";
    cout&lt;&lt;"i = "&lt;&lt;i&lt;&lt;"\n";
    cout&lt;&lt;" After command m=(j--)*(++j) :\n";
    m=(j--)*(++j);// Теперь m=9, а j=2
    cout&lt;&lt;"m = "&lt;&lt;m&lt;&lt;"\n";
    cout&lt;&lt;"j = "&lt;&lt;j&lt;&lt;"\n";
    cout&lt;&lt;" After command n=(--i)*(++i) :\n";
    n=(--i)*(++i);// Теперь n=4, а i=2
    cout&lt;&lt;"n = "&lt;&lt;n&lt;&lt;"\n";
    cout&lt;&lt;"i = "&lt;&lt;i&lt;&lt;"\n";
    return 0;
}</pre></code>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Не знаю почему не догадался до этого